# How do I add printer to AIX menu choices. (Unix operating system)

Tags: unix, printing, alias, aix

I need help assigning an alias name (printer name in menu) to a printer already installed in root mode on AIX 5.3/Unix operating system.  I have added ip address and host name to etc/hosts already.  I have also added the que, enabled printer, and tested printed with success in root mode with (lp -d). But how do I assign the alias and add printer to the AIX menu choices?

```
   Example of AIX 5.3 print choice menu below (Unix)

   Alias
   P1        Printer #2
   P20       Printer #1
   P30       Printer #3
   etc
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not OS configuration. There are at least two Unix/Linux related [se] sites available that might be more suitable, as well as [su]. The [help] on each site has more details on the types of questions that are appropriate for that site.

Comment: What printer list menu are you describing?   AIX doesn't have a "user facing" printer list, besides the ones that view the defined printer queues.   SMIT has an admin UI, but this is based off of /etc/qdaemon and the queue data as well.    Are you describing a menu provided by your application that is running on AIX?